# MPMusicPlayerController being extremely slow (lagging 1+ second)

Tags: swift, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitem

I am trying to make a music player and my app is being really slow when i added the player in there...

I can't switch more than a couple songs within 5 seconds or my app will freeze

```
let myCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: mySongs)
myController.setQueue(with: myCollection)

//setting the album artwork, title, artist and genre... it is way faster when i take it out of the array that I made. when i pluck it from the music player, it is very slow
let mySong = myController.nowPlayingItem


    songTitle.text = mySong?.title
    artistName.text = mySong?.artist
    genreTitle.text = mySong?.genre
    albumArt.image = mySong?.artwork?.image(at: size)


//Skipping stuff when i choose to skip a song.... This is embedded within a gesture... I don't know if thats whats making it slow but it has about a 1 second lag
myController.skipToNextItem()
```

Comment: Join the club... Im afraid MusicKit changing song is incredibly buggy and slow. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/93386

Comment: @JackC I  reported the bug to apple but i don't expect a fix... i don't expect them to fix it any time soon.. I tried running it on a separate processor thread no change

Comment: Unfortunately you're absolutely right. I've seen a few reports to Apple dated from November 2017 which have no reply. Running it on a separate thread stops the UI from freezing up which makes it usable, but doesn't make it any quicker to use.